# EmailTemplate merge fields not working

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a created a trigger on 'Case' which fires after the case stage equals 'Closed Won'. The trigger is working but the Email which gets fired to the related 'Oppy owner' does not have the 'Oppy Name'. The email that is received by the 'Oppy owner';

Hi Rep/Owner, Please close the {!Opportunity.Name} as the related case is closed. Thanks, XYZ

The trigger and trigger handler code is given below;

```
public class NotifyOppyOwnerOnCaseTriggerHandler {

    //Store email template name
    EmailTemplate et = new EmailTemplate();

    //Find closed cases and collect EmailIds on Oppty's
    public List<String> findClosedCases(List<Case> caseList){
        List<String> toAddress = new List<String>();
        //Assuming the relation is setup between oppty and case 
        Map<id,Case> case_map = new Map<id,Case>([Select Id, status,
                                                  Opportunity__r.Owner.email,
                                                  Opportunity__r.Id, Opportunity__r.IsClosed
                                                  From Case Where Status = 'Closed Won' OR Status = 'Closed Lost']);
        //Find out how many new cases got closed and collect emailids
        //for(case c: Trigger.New){
        for(case c: caseList){
            if(case_map.containsKey(c.id)){
                if(case_map.get(c.id).status == 'Closed Won' || case_map.get(c.id).status == 'Closed Lost'){
                    //send email to the oppty owner by extracting oppty owner using case_map.get(c.id).Opportunity__r.Owner.email
                    //store the email ids of the recipients
                    toAddress.add(case_map.get(c.id).Opportunity__r.Owner.email);
                }
            }
        }
        return toAddress;
    }

    public void sendNotification(List<string> toAddress, String tempName){
        et = [SELECT Id, Subject, Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name =:tempName];
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddress);
        mail.setSubject(et.Subject);
        mail.setHtmlBody(et.Body);
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmsg = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        allmsg.add(mail);

        //Catch exceptions while sending email to recipients
        try {
            Messaging.sendEmail(allmsg,false);
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```
    trigger NotifyOppyOwnersOnCaseTrigger on Case (after update) {
  //Specify template name
    String EMAILTEMPLATE ='NotifyRepToCloseOpportunity';

    List<String> toAddress = new List<String>();
  NotifyOppyOwnerOnCaseTriggerHandler handler = new NotifyOppyOwnerOnCaseTriggerHandler();
      if ( Trigger.isUpdate ){
      toAddress = handler.findClosedCases(Trigger.New);
      handler.sendNotification(toAddress, EMAILTEMPLATE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think , the issue is with email template.

From case you have to take opportunity refernce's name.

As per the template , please change as follows :-

Hi Rep/Owner, Please close the {!Case.Opportunity__r.Name} as the related case is closed. Thanks, XYZ

Comment: It is not accepting {!Case.Opportunity__r.Name} in the template.

Comment: Hi I will check ur code and let u know

Comment: It sees that you can't use Cross Object Merge Fields in Email Template, there is an idea in IdeaExchange (https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Brk7AAC) posted for it.

Comment: Hi its kind of correct , also there is some issue calling email template from apex code , the template will work if there is no merge fields. Can you implement the same logic used in trigger and call the email alert , everything will be fine then.